# How to move form from center to right

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I am working on this login/signup form on CodeIgniter.
Got this login/signup code from the internet, but by default, it is in the center. So how do I move this form to the right side of the page?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWvVS.png)

Login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('resources/style.css');?>">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
      
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
          <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Get Started</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div id="login">   
          <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
          
          <button class="button button-block">Log In</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
      </div><!-- tab-content -->
      
</div> <!-- /form -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url('resources/index.js');?>"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Style.css

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #179b77;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
          transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: #1ab188;
}

label.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
          transform: translateY(50px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #ffffff;
}

input, textarea {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #1ab188;
}

textarea {
  border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
  resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.top-row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.top-row > div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #179b77;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

index.js

```js
$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
  
  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');

   if (e.type === 'keyup') {
   if ($this.val() === '') {
          label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
          label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
     if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
   } else {
      label.removeClass('highlight');   
   }   
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {
      
      if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('highlight'); 
   } 
      else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
      label.addClass('highlight');
   }
    }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
  
  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
  
  $(target).fadeIn(600);
  
});
```

Comment: use `right:0px;` in **CSS**  this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add float: right to your content. In your css change form class as below

```
 .form {
    float: right;
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
    margin-right: 20px; /*what ever you want*/
}
```

Comment: Worked, but I want to have a little space between the form and the right corner how to do that?

Comment: @AkhilBiju check my edited answer. If it is useful. Then accept/vote up it

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It is not the issue. Its just because of there is single fields in login form

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This will work

```css
form {
  margin-left: 150px; // Change the number as you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a float property to the form class, alongside with a margin-left of 20 or 30 pixels.

```
.form {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Just add these two to your .form class.

Comment: I don't want it completely at the right end, how can I leave a little space?

Comment: Hmm... Sorry. I think I messed things up a little. Try margin-right instead of margin-left.

Answer (score 0):

```
Working fine!



    $('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
      
      var $this = $(this),
          label = $this.prev('label');

       if (e.type === 'keyup') {
       if ($this.val() === '') {
              label.removeClass('active highlight');
            } else {
              label.addClass('active highlight');
            }
        } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
         if( $this.val() === '' ) {
          label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
       } else {
          label.removeClass('highlight');   
       }   
        } else if (e.type === 'focus') {
          
          if( $this.val() === '' ) {
          label.removeClass('highlight'); 
       } 
          else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
          label.addClass('highlight');
       }
        }

    });

    $('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
      
      e.preventDefault();
      
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      
      target = $(this).attr('href');

      $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
      
      $(target).fadeIn(600);
      
    });
    *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    body {
      background: #c1bdba;
      font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #1ab188;
      -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
      transition: .5s ease;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: #179b77;
    }

    .form {
      background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
      padding: 40px;
      max-width:50%;
      margin: 40px auto;
      border-radius: 4px;
float:right;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
    }

    .tab-group {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    }
    .tab-group:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    .tab-group li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 15px;
      background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
      color: #a0b3b0;
      font-size: 20px;
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
      transition: .5s ease;
    }
    .tab-group li a:hover {
      background: #179b77;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .tab-group .active a {
      background: #1ab188;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .tab-content > div:last-child {
      display: none;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin: 0 0 40px;
    }
input{height:45px;}

    label {
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
              transform: translateY(6px);
      left: 13px;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
      transition: all 0.25s ease;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      pointer-events: none;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    label .req {
      margin: 2px;
      color: #1ab188;
    }

    label.active {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
              transform: translateY(50px);
      left: 2px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    label.active .req {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    label.highlight {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    input, textarea {
      font-size: 22px;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background: none;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 0;
      -webkit-transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
      transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
    }
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
      outline: 0;
      border-color: #1ab188;
    }

    textarea {
      border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
      resize: vertical;
    }

    .field-wrap {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .top-row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    .top-row > div {
      float: left;
      width: 48%;
      margin-right: 4%;
    }
    .top-row > div:last-child {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .button {
      border: 0;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      padding: 15px 0;
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: .1em;
      background: #1ab188;
      color: #ffffff;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    .button:hover, .button:focus {
      background: #179b77;
    }

    .button-block {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .forgot {
      margin-top: -20px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

      
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('resources/style.css');?>">

      
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="form">
          
          <ul class="tab-group">
            <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
          </ul>
          
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="signup">   
              <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
              
              <form action="/" method="post">
              
              <div class="top-row">
                <div class="field-wrap">
                  <label>
                    First Name<span class="req">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
            
                <div class="field-wrap">
                  <label>
                    Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                  Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
              </div>
              
              <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                  Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
              </div>
              
              <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Get Started</button>
              
              </form>

            </div>
            
            <div id="login">   
              <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
              
              <form action="/" method="post">
              
                <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                  Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
              </div>
              
              <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                  Password<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
              </div>
              
              <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
              
              <button class="button button-block">Log In</button>
              
              </form>

            </div>
            
          </div><!-- tab-content -->
          
    </div> <!-- /form -->
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="<?php echo base_url('resources/index.js');?>"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Akhil biju check it now

Comment: @BrianRamsey check it

Comment: @HasmukhBaldaniya  
When I click login the form becomes small. Look here prntscr.com/e401mr   You know how can I keep the form size same?

Comment: @AkhilBiju Yeah I know

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you needed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('resources/style.css');?>">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
      
      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="tab-content" style="float:right;">
        <div id="signup">   
          <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Get Started</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
        <div id="login">   
          <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
          
          <form action="/" method="post">
          
            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
          
          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
          
          <button class="button button-block">Log In</button>
          
          </form>

        </div>
        
      </div><!-- tab-content -->
      
</div> <!-- /form -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url('resources/index.js');?>"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #c1bdba;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #179b77;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.tab-group .active a {
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
          transform: translateY(6px);
  left: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}
label .req {
  margin: 2px;
  color: #1ab188;
}

label.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
          transform: translateY(50px);
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label.active .req {
  opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
  color: #ffffff;
}

input, textarea {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
  transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #1ab188;
}

textarea {
  border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
  resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.top-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.top-row > div {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
.top-row > div:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  background: #179b77;
}

.button-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```js
$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
  
  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');

   if (e.type === 'keyup') {
   if ($this.val() === '') {
          label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
          label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
     if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
   } else {
      label.removeClass('highlight');   
   }   
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {
      
      if( $this.val() === '' ) {
      label.removeClass('highlight'); 
   } 
      else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
      label.addClass('highlight');
   }
    }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
  
  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
  
  $(target).fadeIn(600);
  
});
```